# Cannot NPM Start when requiring tests that require selenium-webdriver in test/index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webpack

So I am trying to setup testing on a JavaScript project using webpack and selenium-webdriver. However when I require my test files from test/index.js file in order to run them in the browser npm start crashes with a series of 'cannot resolve module' errors. The header of my required test looks like this:

```
//=> test/meal_test.js

const assert = require('chai').assert;
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const Meal = require("../lib/meal.js")
const until = webdriver.until;
const frontEndLocation = "http://localhost:8080"

describe('test meal object', function() {
    it('should meal info and food info', function() {
        const meal = new Meal({
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Breakfast",
            "foods": [
                { "id": 4, "name": "Grapes", "calories": 180 },
                { "id": 6, "name": "Yogurt", "calories": 550 },
                { "id": 7, "name": "Macaroni and Cheese", "calories": 950 }
            ]
        })
        assert.equal(meal.id, 1)
        assert.equal(meal.name, 'Breakfast')
        assert(Array.isArray(meal.foods));
        assert.equal(meal.foods.length, 3)
        assert.equal(meal.total, 1680)
    })

})
```

my test/index.js looks like this:

```
//=> test/index.js
require('./meal_test.js')
```

my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./lib/index.js",
        test: "mocha!./test/index.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"] },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', '.css']
    },
};
```

my package.json looks this:

```
{
  "name": "quantified-self-starter-kit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Starter kit for Turing School's BEE M4 Quantified Self Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/turingschool-examples/game-time-starter-kit-FEm1.git"
  },
  "author": "Turing School of Software and Design - Nate Allen",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/turingschool-examples/quantified-self-starter-kit/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/turingschool-examples/quantified-self-starter-kit#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "mocha-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.1",
    "sinon": "^3.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webdriverjs": "^1.7.5",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "0.0.1-security"
  }
}
```

and my crazy errors when running `npm start` look like this:

```
ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js 131:11-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js 20:9-22

ERROR in ./~/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/rimraf
 @ ./~/rimraf/rimraf.js 6:9-22

ERROR in ./~/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/glob
 @ ./~/glob/glob.js 43:9-22

ERROR in ./~/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/fs.realpath
 @ ./~/fs.realpath/index.js 8:9-22

ERROR in ./~/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/fs.realpath
 @ ./~/fs.realpath/old.js 24:9-22

ERROR in ./~/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/glob
 @ ./~/glob/sync.js 4:9-22

ERROR in ./~/tmp/lib/tmp.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/tmp/lib
 @ ./~/tmp/lib/tmp.js 13:11-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js 20:11-35

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js 21:9-22

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js 22:10-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js 20:11-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js 20:21-45

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/edge.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/edge.js 73:11-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js 25:14-38

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js 26:9-22

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/lib/devmode.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/lib/devmode.js 25:11-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/profile.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/profile.js 25:11-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/extension.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/firefox/extension.js 22:11-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/ie.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/ie.js 30:11-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/opera.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/opera.js 75:11-24

ERROR in ./~/selenium-webdriver/phantomjs.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/Home/turing/4module/quantified-self-client/node_modules/selenium-webdriver
 @ ./~/selenium-webdriver/phantomjs.js 47:11-24
```

When I remove the require statement from index.js the build and tests run fine, but then I do not have access to my tests at localhost:3000/test.html.

I have also tried setting `"target": "node"` and `npm install fs --save` to no avail.

I've tried installing some of those module dependancies one by one, but that has not helped either.

It seems directly related to the line: `const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');`

When that line is removed `npm start` works fine.

I'm not sure if this is really an issue or if this is simply the behavior that is expected when using these tools together.

Is there a way to require my end-to-end integrations tests within my index.js and have then run in my test.html?

Any help, insight or advice would be greatly appreciated!